# How to use ViewPager if it is in each list item RecyclerView?

Tags: android, list, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I use `ViewPager` for a horizontal scrolling images in the list `RecyclerView.Adapter.` `ViewPager` uses an adapter that controls the display. Each list item must to load different images. Problem is that during scrolling list (`RecyclerView.Adapter`) in the up and down in `ViewPager` loaded incorrect images - all messed up. I am in `ViewHolder` create new

**Adapter:**

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ViewPagerAdapter vpAdapter;

        public DataObjectHolder(View itemView, int viewType, Context context) {
            super(itemView);

            vpAdapter = new ViewPageAdapter(context);
            viewPager = (ViewPager) itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
            viewPager.setAdapter(vpAdapter);
        }

}
```

then I am in `onBindViewHolder`, using my method, `getImages(List<Images> images)` pass an array of images, based on which the position of a list item (`RecyclerView`):

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

                holder.vpAdapter.setImages(mData.get(position).getImages());

                holder.viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrolled(int pagePosition, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int pagePosition) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                    }
                });

    }
```

method in the `ViewPagerAdapter` looks like this:

```
public void setImages(List<Images> images){
            mImages = images;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and the method `instantiateItem()` in `ViewPagerAdapter` looks like this:

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
        View imgLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemPager, view, false);
        assert imgLayout != null;
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imgLayout.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        Context context = imageView.getContext();
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(mImages.get(position).getImage())
                .resize(300, 300)
                .into(imageView);

        view.addView(imgLayout, 0);
        return imgLayout;
    }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Where correct, is necessary to initialize `ViewPagerAdapter` and how correctly pass a list of images in `ViewPagerAdapter`?

Comment: You should create a `new ViewPagerAdapter()` for each view, likely onBind. I don't think this is going to work well though.

Comment: I tried to create a `new ViewPagerAdapter ()`, in the method `onBind`, but unfortunately it did not fix my problem and still appeared slowdown UI.

Comment: Another approach you can take is to generate (in the recycler adapter constructor) an `ArrayList<ViewPagerAdapter>` with `new ViewPagerAdapter()`s for each position. Then, onBind, you get the n-th ViewPagerAdapter from the array and set it to the view. However, as said, recycling adapter is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks. I should try it, I think it can work. And may be, there are still variants?

Comment: Personally I would replace the ViewPager with HorizontalScrollViews or something like that, and populate them onBind. However, give a try to the array approach.